# Google Map canvas is getting blank when printing (Ctrl + P)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3, printing, html5boilerplate

I'm trying to print the google map canvas that is inside a bootstrap panel just like below:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="map">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to print in a simple way, just pressing `CTRL + P`. But at print visualization box, the map is blank. What could be happening?

Some images:
[image: At page]

At page

[image: At print box]

At print box

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By selectively removing various lines from the `@media print` sections of the Bootstrap CSS I've discovered that my map comes back when I remove the `img {max-width...}` line:

`@media print {
  //...there's other stuff above here
  img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  //...there's other stuff below here 
}`

You can also override the effects of this (vs removing from the BS code) by adding the following somewhere below where you've imported bootstrap:

`@media print {
  img {
    max-width: none !important;
  }
}`

Note that I'm using Sass in the above code samples; I'm on a Rails project, so I'm looking at the BS code via the `bootstrap-sass` gem. The equivalent Less or vanilla CSS should be easy to achieve.

Very much still working on this to see if it's really a fix and/or if this change has collateral damage... may want to isolate this to the `div` containing your map or something.

EDIT: Looks like this line actually comes from the code taken from the HTML5Boilerplate project, which is included in Bootstrap. I've created a minimal demo page and [opened an issue](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1741) about this on the H5BP project.

Update 21 Jul 2016: The fix for this is [slated for inclusion with BS 4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/19000).

Comment: +1 for a 2-4-1. 
This also fixes the same kind of problem with the OS Openspace maps api.

Answer (score 1):

The width of the canvas was too large. I set a limit and it worked.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Wondering if there is a way to only reduce the canvas size as-needed for printing and then re-expanding afterward. I suspect this is Bootstrap related since I can print even a full screen google map just fine on other sites.

Comment: I tried it resizing and firing the `resize` event before and after the print. Didn't work for me :(
I'm also getting some white stripes at print preview when translating the map... zooming in and out rid these stripes of ...